# Помогите разобраться с protected?

Tags: java

Во время подготовки к экзамену OCA по Боярскому, встретил пример на стр.178
Он касается модификатора доступа protected и звучит примерно так, что есть класс 
Bird в пакете bird:

```
package bird;

public class Bird{
    protected String name;
}
```

и есть его наследник Swan в пакете swan:

```
package swan;
import bird.Bird;

public class Swan extends Bird{
   public void check1(){
      System.out.print(name);
   }

   public void check2(){ 
      Swan swan = new Swan();
      System.out.print(swan.name);
   }

   public void check3(){
      Bird bird = new Bird();
      System.out.print(bird.name);
   }
}
```

-check1 компилируется и все хорошо(доступ через наследование)

-сheck2 компилируется, но почему? Я ведь обращаюсь к полю name не через наследование, и не нахожусь в том же пакете что и Bird. Почему тогда name доступен?

-check3 не компилируется вообще, со словами name has protected access in Bird

Comment: В вашем примере `Swan` не наследует `Bird`.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Спасибо, поправил. Вопрос остался актуален(не точно описал вопрос)

Answer (score 1):

Предположим, что `protected name;` в первом блоке кода написан как `protected String name;` и `public class Swan{` во втором блоке кода написан как `public class Swan extends Bird {`

Тогда

сheck2() компилируется потому, что Swan **является наследником** Bird. Соответственно, доступ к protected-полям у него есть.

check3() не компилируется скорее всего потому, что Вы имя объекта bird написали такое же, как имя пакета. Попробуйте его переименовать, т.к. в общем-то check3() выводит то же самое, что нормально компилящийся check1(), а создание объекта класса Bird ни к чему не обязывает и ни на что в данном случае не влияет.

Comment: Заданный вопрос действительно можно решить только при помощи допущений, поскольку сразу же бросается глаза ошибка с объявлением поля в классе Bird. 
Описанные выше допущения кажутся самыми логичными, однако, в таком случае должны скомпилировать все 3 метода.

Comment: @idmitrij2008 исправил код в вопросе.

Answer (score 1):

к protected-членам класса можно получить доступ только внутри наследуемого класса (сheck2 компилируется, он внутри производного класса, получает доступ к защищенному члену базового класса), а вне этого класса (т.е. для объектов производного класса) доступ закрыт. 
Но самое главное, **protected ведет себя так же, как и private для объектов базового класса**! Т.е. доступ для объектов базового класса для защищенных переменных и методов - закрыт.

Bird **bird** = new Bird(); // создали объект базового класса

System.out.print(**bird.name**); /* а тут пытаетесь получить доступ к защищенному (=закрытому) члену этого класса через объект.*/

И кстати, компилятор написал тоже самое. Вчитайтесь просто внимательнее: "name has protected access in Bird" - свойство name является защищенным в Bird, т.е. к нему невозможно получить доступ вне этого класса, т.е. объекты этого класса не смогут получить доступ к name (так  же как и к private-членам).

Answer (score 0):

Если при создании класса Class2 пакета package2 используется наследование от класса Class1 из пакета package1, то Class2 получает доступ только к public членам Class1. 
Бывают случаи, когда это нужно.

Таким образом protected даёт доступ внутри пакета - везде, в других пакетах - только в наследниках.