# Почему не виден метод x.abc() в методе ghi() при наследовании, хотя у метода модификатор доступа protected (java)

Tags: java

Не понимаю, почему в методе ghi() при выполнении метода x.abc(), выдается ошибка  'abc()' has protected access in 'Lesson23.X.X2'  хотя стоит модификатор protected, который при наследовании применяется и всё должно работать как надо. Не обращайте внимание на результат выполнения программы, просто интересен механизм работы java.  Не понимаю логику работы java здесь, объясните, добрые люди

```
public class X2 {
    protected void abc(){
        System.out.println("X2");
    }
}
```

```
public class Y2 extends X2 {

    public void abc() {
        System.out.println("y2");
    }

    public void ghi() {
        X2 x = new Y2();
        x.abc();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Y2 a = new Y2();
        a.ghi();
    }
}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Помогите разобраться с protected?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/983176/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%81-protected)

Comment: Странно... Я запустил ваш код и всё работает... Выводится `y2`...